Implementing ethercat_ros2 for Invt DA200 Motor Drivers in Position Mode
I want to run a servo motor by using a Invt DA200 series motor driver with ROS2 humble. After a quick search I have found ethercat_ros2. I have attempted to run the motor in the Profile Velocity (Mode 3) and Interpolation Position (Mode 8). It can be run succesfully in the Profile Velocity by using ethercat_ros2. However, I cannot set the position of the motor shaft in the Mode 8.
When I have launched position_invt_motor_driver.launch.py
# Copyright 2023 ICube Laboratory, University of Strasbourg
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument


from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():


   # Declare arguments
   declared_arguments = []
   declared_arguments.append(
       DeclareLaunchArgument(
           'description_file',
           default_value='invt_motor_driver.config.xacro',
           description='URDF/XACRO description file with the axis.',
       )
   )


   description_file = LaunchConfiguration('description_file')


   # Get URDF via xacro
   robot_description_content = Command(
       [
           PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
           " ",
           PathJoinSubstitution(
               [
                   FindPackageShare("invt_da200_bringup"),
                   "description/config",
                   description_file,
               ]
           ),
       ]
   )
   robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}


   robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
       [
           FindPackageShare("invt_da200_bringup"),
           "config",
           "controllers.yaml",
       ]
   )


   control_node = Node(
       package="controller_manager",
       executable="ros2_control_node",
       parameters=[robot_description, robot_controllers],
       output="both",
   )
   robot_state_pub_node = Node(
       package="robot_state_publisher",
       executable="robot_state_publisher",
       output="both",
       parameters=[robot_description],
   )


   joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
       package="controller_manager",
       executable="spawner",
       arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
   )




   trajectory_controller_spawner = Node(
       package="controller_manager",
       executable="spawner",
       arguments=["trajectory_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
   )




   nodes = [
       control_node,
       robot_state_pub_node,
       joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
       trajectory_controller_spawner
   ]


   return LaunchDescription(
       declared_arguments +
       nodes)

And start to publish:
$ros2 topic pub /trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory trajectory_msgs/msg/JointTrajectory "header:
  stamp:
    sec: 0
    nanosec: 0
  frame_id: ''
joint_names: ['joint_1']
points:
- positions: [5000]
  time_from_start:
    sec: 2
    nanosec: 0"

There are no position change
While I am rotating the motor shaft
$ros2 topic echo /joint_states

---

header:
stamp:
sec: 1730725332
nanosec: 736825772
frame_id: ''
name:
- joint_1
position:
- 2198.0
velocity:
- 0.0
effort:
- .nan
---

Observing 0x607a (Position command)
$watch -n 0.1 "ethercat upload -p 0 0x607a 0x00 --type int32"

0x00000896 2198

Observing 0x6064 (Actual position)
$watch -n 0.1 "ethercat upload -p 0 0x6064 0x00 --type int32"

0x00000896 2198


Visually, everything appears to be functioning correctly. The motor converges to the given position (5000 in this case). When I slightly push it back to a position less than 5000 or push it forward to a position greater than 5000, it gradually rotates back toward the set value (5000) in a step-by-step manner.
I have checked 0x6060 (mode of operation register) from the terminal interface and the panel of the motor driver. It has been set correctly.
I hope I have clearly defined the problem. If you need more information, please feel free to ask.
Yusuf
